# Find greatest value of $a^2+b^2$

Tags: functions

***If $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+4x+ a \sin x + b\cos x ~ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is an injection then the greatest value of $a^2+b^2$ is _______?***

To ensure injection, we must ensure that there is no maxima/minima in any interval which is equivalent to $f'(x)\neq 0$.

Note that $f'(x)=3x^2+6x+4+a \cos x - b \sin x \neq 0$. It can be observed that $3x^2+6x+4>0$ with its minimum value being $1$.

So, our condition can be reduced to $a \cos x - b \sin x > -1$.

Again, $a \cos x - b \sin x +1$ can be written as $\frac{a}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}} \cos (-x) - \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin (-x) +1$ such that $\sin (\theta -x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}} >0$.

I couldn't proceed anymore!

Comment: Statement after "so" is incorrect.

Comment: @Mathbg: Is this problem a homework question ? if so which book is it from?

Comment: @DeepSea It's from a practice paper and not any book.

Comment: Do you have the lecture notes related to this question that you can incorporate it into this post ?

Comment: @DeepSea It would be quite hard actually. Functions, as a whole, were being taught and there's quite a lot of it.

Comment: "To ensure injection, we must ensure that there is no maxima/minima in any interval which is equivalent to $f'(x)\neq 0$. " Not accurate: consider $y = x^3$

Comment: @Ovi Yes, I don't think there's going to be any inflection point in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing $t=x+1$, rewrite the requirement on $f'(x)$ as:
$$
3t^2+1+A\cos(t+\phi) \ge 0.
$$
To maximize the value of $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ the expression should attend its minimal value as far from $t=0$ as possible, which corresponds to the choice $\phi=0$.

In this case for sufficiently large $A$ two symmetric minima on both sides of $t=0$ will appear. If $A$ is increased further the minima become negative.

The critical values of the parameters $A$ and $t$ correspond to the case when the function value in the minima is 0:
$$\begin{cases}
3t^2+1+A\cos t&=0\\
6t-A\sin t&=0
\end{cases}.
$$
For the critical value of $t$ one obtains then the equation:
$$
(3t^2+1)\sin t+6t\cos t=0,
$$
which minimal positive solution is:
$$
t_*\approx2.49037.
$$

The corresponding value of $A$ is:
$$
A_*=\frac{6t_*}{\sin t_*}\approx24.6508.
$$

Its square gives the greatest possible value of $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: The downvoting person is welcome to point out an error (if it is present) or otherwise explain his/her decision.